# Apache Spark - org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, gradient-descent

When attempting to run my method:

```
    def doGD() = {
       allRatings.foreach(rating => gradientDescent(rating));
    }
```

I get the error: `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serialisable`

I understand that my method of Gradient Descent is not going to parallelise because each step depends upon the previous step - so working in parallel is not an option. However, from the Console if I do this:

```
    val gd = new GradientDescent()
    gd.doGD();
```

I get the error as mentioned.

However, if in the Console I do this:

```
    val gd = new GradientDescent()
    gd.allRatings.foreach(rating => gradientDescent(rating))
```

It works perfectly fine. As you may have noticed what works in the 2nd example is the same code as in the first example except instead of a method I just take the code out of the method and call it directly.

Why does the one work and the other does not? I'm bemused.

(Additional note: Class `GradientDescent extends Serializable` ).

The `gradientDescent` method:

```
def gradientDescent(rating : Rating) = { 

var userVector = userFactors.get(rating.user).get
var itemVector = itemFactors.get(rating.product).get

userFactors.map(x => if(x._1 == rating.user)(x._1, x._2 += 0.02 * (calculatePredictionError(rating.rating, userVector, itemVector) * itemVector)))
userVector = userFactors.get(rating.user).get // updated user vector

itemFactors.map(x => if(x._1 == rating.product)(x._1, x._2 += 0.02 * (calculatePredictionError(rating.rating, userVector, itemVector) * itemVector)))
}
```

I know I'm using 2 vars stored on the master - `userFactors` and `itemFactors` - and as the process is sequential parallelising is not possible. But this doesn't explain why calling the method from the Console does not work but re-writing the inners of the method in the Console does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to tell without full source of `GradientDescent` class, but you're probably capturing an unserializable value. When running the method, it needs to serialize the full object and send it to the workers, while inlined version doesn't.

Comment: Could you explain why a value could be unserialisable? I'm really just wondering why it doesn't work when calling the method `doGD()` but does work when I write the code that is within the method! Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Detailed code that cleans closures is here: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/ef4ff00f87a4e8d38866f163f01741c2673e41da/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/ClosureCleaner.scala
In summary any references to spark context, or open resources (sockets, files, etc) cause the task to not be serializable

Comment: Thanks, Dan. However, I'm not too sure what you have linked me to. I have added the Gradient Descent method into my question if you care to take a look.

Comment: Note that dependencies are transitive. It looks like `gradientDescent` references lots of other objects. Are some RDDs? Do they reference file/socket handles transitively, etc. The JVM will attempt to serialize the tree of dependencies.

Comment: for a overall understanding of    Spark serialization   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40818001/understanding-spark-serialization/40818002?sfb=2#40818002