# Accessing HashMap inside flatMapToPair

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop

Edit: Already solved using `RDD.collectAsMap()`

I am trying to replicate the solution to the problem from pages 28-30 of http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2016/presentation/S6424-michela-taufer-apache-spark.pdf

I have a HashMap that I instantiate outside of the map function. The HashMap contains the following data:

```
{1:2, 2:3, 3:2, 4:2, 5:3}
```

A previously defined RDD previousRDD was has the type:

```
JavaPairRDD<Integer, Iterable<Tuple2<Integer, Integer>>>
```

has the data:

```
1: [(1,2), (1,5)]
2: [(2,1), (2,3), (2,5)]
3: [(3,2), (3,4)]
4: [(4,3), (4,5)]
5: [(5,1), (5,2), (5,4)]
```

I try to create a new RDD with a flatMapToPair:

```
JavaPairRDD<Integer, Integer> newRDD = previousRDD.flatMapToPair(new PairFlatMapFunction<Tuple2<Integer, Iterable<Tuple2<Integer, Integer>>>, Integer, Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Iterator<Tuple2<Integer, Integer>> call(Tuple2<Integer, Iterable<Tuple2<Integer, Integer>>> integerIterableTuple2) throws Exception {
        Integer count;
        ArrayList<Tuple2<Integer, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
        count = hashMap.get(integerIterableTuple2._1);
        for (Tuple2<Integer, Integer> t : integerIterableTuple2._2) {
            Integer tcount = hashMap.get(t._2);
            if (count < tcount || (count.equals(tcount) && integerIterableTuple2._1 < t._2)) {
                list.add(t);
            }
        }
        return list.iterator();
    }
});
```

But in this, the `hashMap.get(t._2)` inside the for loop gets NULLs most of the time. I have checked that the proper values are inside the HashMap.

Is there a way to properly get the values of a HashMap inside a Spark function?

Comment: Is hashMap declared in method or as class variable?

Comment: It's declared as a class variable.

Comment: Actually, I was wrong. It's declared in the main method.

Answer (score 0):

It should work. Spark should capture your variable, serialize it and send to each worker with each task. You might try broadcasting this map

```
sc.broadcast(hashMap)
```

and use the result instead of `hashMap`. It is more efficient memory-wise too (shared storage per executor).

Comment: I save the result of the above to a Broadcast variable. However, when I do `broadcast.getValue().get(key)` inside the Spark function, every key (even those that previously worked) returns null.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with class variables. You can try make your variable local or  declare one more, like this:

```
 Map localMap = hashMap;
 JavaPairRDD<Integer, Integer> newRDD = previousRDD.flatMapToPair(
   ...
      Integer tcount = localMap.get(t._2);
   ...
 );
```

I think this is due to spark serialization mechanism. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40818002/9630486).

Comment: This is what I do. I declare the HashMap like you did, I perform a `forEach` on an RDD, and I populate the HashMap. Then, I perform a `flatMapToPair` with `previousRDD`, and I get the value for each key.