# Java Spark Dataset MapFunction - Task not serializable without any reference to class

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I have a following class that reads csv data into Spark's `Dataset`. Everything works fine if I just simply read and return the `data`.

However, if I apply a `MapFunction` to the `data` before returning from function, I get

`Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable`

`Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.Workflow`.

I know Spark's working and its need to serialize objects for distributed processing, however, I'm NOT using any reference to `Workflow` class in my mapping logic. I'm not calling any `Workflow` class function in my mapping logic. So why is Spark trying to serialize `Workflow` class? Any help will be appreciated.

```
public class Workflow {

    private final SparkSession spark;   

    public Dataset<Row> readData(){
        final StructType schema = new StructType()
            .add("text", "string", false)
            .add("category", "string", false);

        Dataset<Row> data = spark.read()
            .schema(schema)
            .csv(dataPath);

        /* 
         * works fine till here if I call
         * return data;
         */

        Dataset<Row> cleanedData = data.map(new MapFunction<Row, Row>() {
            public Row call(Row row){
                /* some mapping logic */
                return row;
            }
        }, RowEncoder.apply(schema));

        cleanedData.printSchema();
        /* .... ERROR .... */
        cleanedData.show();

        return cleanedData;
    }
}
```

Comment: see if this helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40818001/understanding-spark-serialization#:~:text=Object%20serialization%20is%20needed%20if,or%20transmitted%20over%20the%20network%20.&text=Rule%20of%20thumb%20while%20understanding,and%20sent%20to%20the%20executors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

anonymous inner classes have a hidden/implicit reference to enclosing class. use Lambda expression or go with Roma Anankin's solution

Answer (score 0):

you could make Workflow  implement Serializeble and SparkSession as @transient

Comment: while this may work, it does not answer the question i.e. why is Spark trying to serialize ```Workflow``` when I'm not making any reference to it in the ```map``` function.