# Spark error handling - Inside Dataset map operation

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to collect all errors that occurred during a map operation and then write the error to individual files for each item.

Below is the sample code. (It's not the exact code. The list of strings will be replaced by custom type and will hold some values used in map iteration, ex. actual dataset may have a id, sequence number and string data, so if error occurs I should have info of id and sequence number in error collection along with error message.)

```
List<String> errorList = new ArrayList<>();

Dataset<Integer> ds = spark.createDataset(Arrays.asList(1111, 0, 31111, 0, 51111, 61111, 71111, 0),
        Encoders.INT());

Dataset<Integer> result = ds.map((MapFunction<Integer, Integer>) value -> {
    try {
        System.out.print(value);
        if (value / 0 == 0)
            System.out.println("sucess");

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        errorList.add("error occured for - " + value);
    }
    return value;
}, Encoders.INT());

errorList.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

I don't see the output from errorlist (running this spark from eclipse IDE in local mode).
Is there any mistake or this type of global variable concept not possible?

Answer (score 0):

You initialize list on driver, then `map` is running on executor.
`errorList` will be serialized, sent to executors and deserialized so errors will be added to copy of `errorList`.
Then you try to print values of `errorList` on driver which obviously is empty.

If you want to collect errors on driver you can return errors in `map`.

More about spark serialization https://stackoverflow.com/a/40818002/9630486.